# How can i fetch array of nested arrays sequentially?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, promise, fetch

I have two nested arrays that contain urls, for example:

`[['http://ex.com/1','http://ex.com/2'],['http://ex.com/3']]`

How can i fetch urls from the first array simultaneously and fetch url from the second array after resolving the first array ?

Comment: using `fetch` and `Promise.all` would be a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all()` to fetch couple of urls at once.

```js
async function getResponses (arr) {
  const res = []
  for (const urls of arr) {
    // Fetch all urls at once
    const responses = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)))
    res.push(await Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.text())))
  }

  return res
}
```

If your responses are in JSON then you can use

```js
responses.map(response => response.json())
```